# Как редактировать html из админки django

Tags: python, html, django

У меня есть фон(`carousel`) на сайте, который стоило бы менять из админки **Django**, что бы постоянно не лезть в код:

```
<div class="item home__cover" data-bg="{% static 'img/home/home__bg.jpg' %}"></div>
<div class="item home__cover" data-bg="{% static 'img/home/home__bg2.jpg' %}"></div>
<div class="item home__cover" data-bg="{% static 'img/home/home__bg3.jpg' %}"></div>
<div class="item home__cover" data-bg="{% static 'img/home/home__bg4.jpg' %}"></div>
```

К примеру, вывести данные 4-е блока в админке, и вставлять туда ссылку. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай модель с путями к картинкам.

```
class Carousel(Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

и добавь её в админку. (Потом можно её переделать на аплоад картинок с админки.)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Carousel

class CarouselAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Carousel, CarouselAdmin)
```

В html шаблоне пропиши:

```
{% for o in carousel %}
   <div class="item home__cover" data-bg="{% static o.filename %}".</div>
{% endfor %}
```

И передай `Carousel.objects.all()` в шаблон как carousel

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Получается, у `Django` нету Какого нибудь блока? Нужно отдельную модель создавать?

Comment: Редактировать сам файл можно, но кеши и все такое.. Оно не заработает без перезапуска на проде